# improve the adding performance of a collection

Tags: c#, performance, collections

I am implementing my collection:

SpecialCollection class:

```
public class SpecialCollection<TId, TName, TValue> : Dictionary<CompositeKey<TId, TName>, TValue>
    {

        #region Private fileds

        private Dictionary<CompositeKey<TId, TName>, TValue> _baseDictionary = null;
        private ReaderWriterLockSlim _readWriteLockSlim = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

        #endregion

        #region Constructors

        public SpecialCollection()
        {
            _baseDictionary = new Dictionary<CompositeKey<TId, TName>, TValue>();
        }

        #endregion

        public void Add(CompositeKey<TId, TName> compositeKey, TValue value)
        {
            _readWriteLockSlim.EnterWriteLock();

            try
            {
                _baseDictionary.Add(compositeKey, value);
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            catch (ArgumentException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                _readWriteLockSlim.ExitWriteLock();
            }
        }
}
```

CompositeKey class:

```
public struct CompositeKey<TId, TName> : IEquatable<Tuple<TId, TName>>
    {
        public TId Id;
        public TName Name;

        public CompositeKey(TId id, TName name)
        {
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                return false;

            if (this.GetType() != obj.GetType())
                return false;

            return AreEqual(this, (CompositeKey<TId, TName>)obj);
        }

        public bool Equals(CompositeKey<TId, TName> other)
        {
            return AreEqual(this, other);
        }

        private static bool AreEqual(CompositeKey<TId, TName> a, CompositeKey<TId, TName> b)
        {
            if (!a.Id.Equals(b.Id))
                return false;

            if (!a.Name.Equals(b.Name))
                return false;

            return true;
        }

        public static bool operator == (CompositeKey<TId, TName> a, CompositeKey<TId, TName> b)
        {
            return AreEqual(a, b);
        }

        public static bool operator != (CompositeKey<TId, TName> a, CompositeKey<TId, TName> b)
        {
            return !AreEqual(a, b);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Id.GetHashCode() ^ Name.GetHashCode();
        }

        public bool Equals(Tuple<TId, TName> other)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

I faced with a question related to performance. For example, the adding of 10000 elements to my collection takes `9745` milliseconds. But the adding of 10000 elements to ConcurrentDictionary takes `4965` milliseconds.

If add 30000 elements to my collection, it takes a lot of time - about `40000` milliseconds.

I have no idea how to improve the performance :( Could you please to tell how can I improve the performance of my collection if it is possible? May be, the performance related to CompositeKey class?

Edit:

I tested the performance like this:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<CompositeKey<int, int>, int> cd = new ConcurrentDictionary<CompositeKey<int, int>, int>();
            SpecialCollection<int, int, int> sc = new SpecialCollection<int, int, int>();

            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                cd.TryAdd(new CompositeKey<int, int>(i, i), i);
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            sw.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                sc.Add(new CompositeKey<int, int>(i, i), i);

            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Side question - why catch and rethrow exceptions? No benefits except number of code lines

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use a `ConcurrentDictionary` inside your custom collection?

Comment: Because I need to implements own concurrent collection :) Sergey Berezovskiy, in order to stack trace starts from my class, but if you have better variant of exceptions processing for my collections, just say :)

Comment: Unless this is a homework assignment, you never "need to" implement your own collection. You may need to implement some feature that requires a collection, sure. But I would always prefer existing collections over rolling my own.

Comment: Of course! As you can see I use Dictionary<CompositeKey<TId, TName> in "my collection", but may be I need to change CompositeKey class in order to improve the performance for SpecialCollection?

Comment: how are you testing the performance?

Comment: I have added the code example.

Comment: What is it that your collection does that you can't use a `ConcurrentDictionary` for?

Comment: And catching and rethrowing an Exception like that does nothing. The result is identical to not catching at all.

Comment: Given the code, the only reasonable place for optimizations would be hashcode generation and equality testing, performance would directly depend on that, depending on the amount of collisions. That, and the amount of thread contention.

Comment: Ben Aaronson, I cannot use `ConcurrentDictionary`, because it is a requirement.

Comment: Maybe, then, it's better to ask what the requirements are? I've never had requirements handed to me that said "do not use X", unless it also specified *why* "X" should not be used.

Comment: @BenAaronson Catching and re-throwing by `throw` would be identical to not catching at all. Re-throwing with `throw ex;` results in a different (new) stack trace for the exception.

Comment: @Rik Ah, quite right! Though that's more of a disadvantage than a reason to do it this way.

Comment: @BenAaronson i would say so, too, but it appears OP's doing this consciously, see his first comment above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tested this myself, and there is almost no difference in performance. Given your test code, it's likely that the difference in performance was because you don't reset your stopwatch in between tests. As [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.stop.aspx) says:

> When a Stopwatch instance measures more than one interval, the Stop method is equivalent to pausing the elapsed time measurement. A subsequent call to Start resumes measuring time from the current elapsed time value. Use the Reset method to clear the cumulative elapsed time in a Stopwatch instance.

So simply add an `sw.Reset()` between tests.

In my tests, I did manage to get a very small performance improvement by using the `lock` keyword instead of a `ReaderWriterLockSlim`, though it may have been random.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about `sw.Reset()`:(
What do you about if I will use `lock` keyword for writing method (like `Add`), but `ReaderWriterLockSlim#EnterReadLock` for reading methods (like `GetValue`)? Is it good practice?

Comment: @elias I don't think that would work since two threads could call different methods which use different locks. Then they'd each think they had an exclusive lock but actually be accessing the underlying resource at the same time

Answer (score 1):

`ReaderWriterLockSlim#EnterWriteLock` seems a lot slower than a simple C# monitor lock. Since `ConcurrentDictionary` uses simple locks (as many as the concurrency level parameter), this may be the source of your performance problem.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static object lock1 = new object();
        private static ReaderWriterLockSlim lock2 = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

        public static int DoLock1(int value)
        {
            lock (lock1)
                return value;
        }

        public static int DoLock2(int value)
        {
            lock2.EnterWriteLock();
            try
            {
                return value;
            }
            finally
            {
                lock2.ExitWriteLock();
            }

        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
            {
                DoLock1(i);
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
            {
                DoLock2(i);

            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What do you about if I will use `lock` keyword for writing method (like `Add`), but `ReaderWriterLockSlim#EnterReadLock` for reading methods (like `GetValue`)? Is it good practice?